# How can I convert a String to a String[] // Android development // Java

Tags: java, android

I am quite new to Java and am currently coding an Android application. In my "Shortcuts" class, I have this bit of code (more of course, but not useful to you, I don't think):

```
final String[] items = new String[]{ "Please select a category",scanner.getCategorys() };
        @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        selection.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I have another class named "Scanner", which has this code:

```
String categorys = "test";

public String getCategorys() {
    return categorys;
}
```

This does work, and in my Spinner, I can fill in my "Please select a category" option with a single value (i.e "test"). The problem is, I would like to be able to select multiple categories. If I do this in "Shortcuts" class:

```
final String[] items = new String[]{ "Please select a category","test","test2" };
```

It would work, but I would like to set it from the "Scanner" class, so I tried this:

```
String[] categorys = "test","test2";

public String[] getCategorys() {
    return categorys;
}
```

But it just gives me the error:

```
String cannot be converted to String[]
```

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
String[] categorys = "test","test2";
```

Change it to

```
String[] categorys = {"test","test2"};
```

Comment: Thanks, that removed some errors, but I still get errors where I put scanner.getCategorys(). I've edited the post.

Comment: Yes it will. Just place `String[] categorys {"Please select a category", "test","test2"}`. Then initialize your items like that: `String[] items = scanner.getCategorys()`

Answer (score 1):

In your last code sample, you have to put `{ }` around your strings, like so:

```
String[] categorys = { "test","test2" };

public String[] getCategorys() {
    return categorys;
}
```

According to your edit above, you can't add a String[] to an existing String[]. You need to add every item in the String[] you get from `getCategorys()` to the other array. I would probably switch to an `ArrayList<string>` in this case, so you don't have to decide what size the array should be, then add each item.

Comment: Thanks, that removed some errors, but I still get errors where I put scanner.getCategorys()

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize categorys as follows

```
String[] categorys = {"test","test2"};
```

I'd call the variable as 'categories'.

EDIT :
scanner.getCategorys() cannot be used as the constructor expects a String and not a string array. A good idea would be use ArrayList as pointed out by uncocoder. You could then just use the add method to include "Please select a category".

Comment: Thanks, that removed some errors, but I still get errors where I put scanner.getCategorys(). I've edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

I recomment to use ArrayList, it's fast and easy like this

```
ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
strings.add("SOME TEXT");
strings.get(0);
//and more
```